# Different background-color for each cell of the first row and first column in a CSS table

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-table

I'm trying to add a different background color to each cell of the first row and first column of a table.

This is what it should look like:

[image: Itinerary]

I found a selector to apply different color to the cells of the first row but now I'm stuck with the cells of the first column (Morning, Afternoon and Evening). I managed to get them all blue but each of them should actually have a different shade of blue...). This is my CSS code:

```
table.agenda {
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;}

table.agenda td, table.agenda th {
border: 1px solid #fff;
padding: 8px;
text-align: center;}

table.agenda td {
padding-top: 12px;
padding-bottom: 12px;
background-color: rgb(193, 212, 174);
color: black;}

th:nth-child(1) { background: white; }
th:nth-child(2) { background: rgb(72, 151, 54); color: white;}
th:nth-child(3) { background: rgb(84, 155, 64); color: white;}
th:nth-child(4) { background: rgb(97, 160, 73); color: white;}
th:nth-child(5) { background: rgb(110, 165, 82); color: white;}
th:nth-child(6) { background: rgb(120, 169, 91); color: white;}

table.agenda tr td:first-child { background: rgb(16, 69, 142); color: white;}
```

and this is my HTML code:

```
<table class="agenda">
<thead>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th>August 4</th>
<th>August 5</th>
<th>August 6</th>
<th>August 7</th>
<th>August 8</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Morning</td>
<td>Day 1 Morning</td>
<td>Day 2 Morning</td>
<td>Day 3 Morning</td>
<td>Day 4 Morning</td>
<td>Day 5 Morning</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Afternoon</td>
<td>Day 1 Afternoon</td>
<td>Day 2 Afternoon</td>
<td>Day 3 Afternoon</td>
<td>Day 4 Afternoon</td>
<td>Day 5 Afternoon</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Evening</td>
<td>Day 1 Evening</td>
<td>Day 2 Evening</td>
<td>Day 3 Evening</td>
<td>Day 4 Evening</td>
<td>Day 5 Evening</td>
</tr> 
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: are you able to alter the html at all?

Comment: if you can change the html, why don't you just add classes?

Comment: Thanks,for your help! Code from Maximilian Laumeister and scaisEdge work like a charm and I'm very grateful! sorry for the late reply, first time I posted a question here and I thought I would get an email notification as soon as someone posts an answer....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can modify the colors of each cell in the first column without modifying the HTML by combining `nth-child` on the `tr` and `first-child` on the `td` like this:

```
table.agenda tr:nth-child(1) td:first-child {
  background: rgb(16, 20, 50);
  color: white;
}

table.agenda tr:nth-child(2) td:first-child {
  background: rgb(16, 69, 150);
  color: white;
}

table.agenda tr:nth-child(3) td:first-child {
  background: rgb(16, 69, 255);
  color: white;
}
```

**Working Live Demo:**

```css
table.agenda {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

table.agenda td,
table.agenda th {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center;
}

table.agenda td {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  background-color: rgb(193, 212, 174);
  color: black;
}

th:nth-child(1) {
  background: white;
}

th:nth-child(2) {
  background: rgb(72, 151, 54);
  color: white;
}

th:nth-child(3) {
  background: rgb(84, 155, 64);
  color: white;
}

th:nth-child(4) {
  background: rgb(97, 160, 73);
  color: white;
}

th:nth-child(5) {
  background: rgb(110, 165, 82);
  color: white;
}

th:nth-child(6) {
  background: rgb(120, 169, 91);
  color: white;
}

table.agenda tr:nth-child(1) td:first-child {
  background: rgb(16, 20, 50);
  color: white;
}

table.agenda tr:nth-child(2) td:first-child {
  background: rgb(16, 69, 150);
  color: white;
}

table.agenda tr:nth-child(3) td:first-child {
  background: rgb(16, 69, 255);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table class="agenda">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>August 4</th>
      <th>August 5</th>
      <th>August 6</th>
      <th>August 7</th>
      <th>August 8</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Morning</td>
      <td>Day 1 Morning</td>
      <td>Day 2 Morning</td>
      <td>Day 3 Morning</td>
      <td>Day 4 Morning</td>
      <td>Day 5 Morning</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Afternoon</td>
      <td>Day 1 Afternoon</td>
      <td>Day 2 Afternoon</td>
      <td>Day 3 Afternoon</td>
      <td>Day 4 Afternoon</td>
      <td>Day 5 Afternoon</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Evening</td>
      <td>Day 1 Evening</td>
      <td>Day 2 Evening</td>
      <td>Day 3 Evening</td>
      <td>Day 4 Evening</td>
      <td>Day 5 Evening</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/wyh11L66/1/

Answer (score 2):

for the row you can use this 
(you must adjust the color, i copied your color from header)

```
tr:nth-child(1) td:first-child { background: rgb(72, 151, 54); color: white;}
tr:nth-child(2) td:first-child  { background: rgb(72, 151, 54); color: white;}
tr:nth-child(3) td:first-child  { background: rgb(72, 151, 54); color: white;}
```

Comment: Nice +1, just correct it like this: `tr:nth-child(1) td:first-child`  and `tr:nth-child(2) td:first-child` and `tr:nth-child(3) td:first-child` https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/dLhbe9da/

Comment: You welcome, but the sequence of the `tr:nth-child` still shifted, it needs to be 1,2 and 3 instead

Comment: No the first tr is white when start with the second

Comment: You're right but the first row in the OP table is `<tr><th>..` not `<tr><td>..`

Comment: But i think the tr numbering remain the same, is not relatedwith the td child

Comment: @scaisEdge The `tr`s that we want to style are the first, second, and third children of their parent, the `tbody` element. Using this type of selector, the `th` doesn't come into the picture at all.